# RecurrenceTable runs very slowly when doing exact arithmetic

Tags: numerics, symbolic

I am a newbie to Mathematica. I wanted to generate a sequence of numbers with the following command:

```
RecurrenceTable[
  {a[n + 1] == 4 a[n]*(1 - a[n]), a[0] == 1/√3, a, {n, 0, 100000}]
```

but it takes endless time to complete.

So I switch to:

```
RecurrenceTable[
  {a[n + 1] == 4 a[n](1 - a[n]), a[0] == 0.5773502691896258}, a, {n, 0, 100000}]
```

It completes in no time.

What is reason behind that?

Comment: The first is calculating to infinite precision, `Precision[1/\[Sqrt]3]`, and the second to machine precision, `Precision[N[1/\[Sqrt]3]]`.

Comment: In addition to what @Edmund said: I suggest you try evaluating both tables with fewer elements (say, 10 instead of 100000). You'll see that both have very different kinds of output.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, try it with `3.` instead of `3` and you should see a similar result.

Answer (score 6):

Before using [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html), I recommend that you try finding the closed-form expression using [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html).

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {a[n + 1] == 4*a[n]*(1 - a[n]), a[0] == 1/√3};

a2[n_] = a[n] /. RSolve[eqns, a[n], n][[1]] // Simplify
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
eqns /. a -> a2 // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)

m = 9;
(a2 /@ Range[0, m]) == 
  RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 4*a[n]*(1 - a[n]), a[0] == 1/√3}, 
   a, {n, 0, m}] // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```